# Two fields in a table related to a field in another table

Tags: yii2

I have a model/table **solicitation** with 2 fields (**user_id** and **analyst_id**) related to field **id** in model table **user**.

In my view, i have a gridview with fields:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'user_id',
    'enableSorting' => true,
    'value' => function ($model) {                      
               return $model->user->username;
           },
]
```

How do same with analyst_id (i need show the username based another id) ?

**UPDATE**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create another relation for analyst:

Add in model:

```
public function getAnalyst()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'analyst_id']);
}
```

Displaying in GridView:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'analyst_id',
    'enableSorting' => true,
    'value' => function ($model) {                      
        return $model->analyst->username;
    },
],
```

Or if the analyst might not exist replace `return` part:

```
return $model->analyst ? $model->analyst->username : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
  'value' => function ($model) {                      
                return User::findOne($model->analyst_id)->username;
            },
```

PS Add the correct namespace for User

Comment: I think you should not write such queries in view.

Comment: my user model is:
`use amnah\yii2\user\models\User;`

Comment: I do in my *TaskSearch* model?

Comment: It's better to use another relation for that. Check my answer.

Comment: Relation should be placed in main model, not search model.

Comment: @arogachev
`Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: If analyst might not exist, obviously this exception will be thrown. Just add check for that, I covered this in my answer. Did you see it?

Comment: ah yes, now I understand here